# PHP multiple events sending

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I`m working on application which prviding clients to use calendar and creating some events there (I mean calendar in my app). Some of clients are have more than 1000 events in calendar and I want to start using Google Calendar . But I cant find any way to send multiple events in Google Calendar by 1 request.

**Question**: Is it possible to send few events in 1 request by using php-sdk, which google provides or by any other way such a http request?

**Upd**: I saw batch requests in google calendar docs, but Im not sure that its working now and how do I need to use it

Thanks!

Comment: You can read the documentation to find that out. the SDK can't support anything the backend API doesn't support. https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference. But if you want to do a one-off migration, it's not so bad to send 1000 requests, just spread them out so you don't go over your regular limit.

Comment: Sending batch requests is dead. https://developers.google.com/calendar/batch - see the big red box?

Comment: https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html explains how to migrate to API-specific batch requests, if they exist.

Comment: _global_ batch requests are dead, but you can still send batch requests with the calendar api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you would be using is [events.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) this method `Creates an event` as in singular there is no way to send a request that would send more than one.

You could use [batching](https://developers.google.com/calendar/batch) but all batching really is is sending X number of event.inserts in a single batch request. Its not going to save you on quota the quota cost will be the same the only thing it will save you on is on the number of HTTP calls you are making.

> Global HTTP Batch Endpoints ([www.googleapis.com/batch](http://www.googleapis.com/batch)) will cease to work on August 12, 2020 as announced on the Google Developers blog. For instructions on transitioning services to use API-specific HTTP Batch Endpoints ([www.googleapis.com/batch/api/version](http://www.googleapis.com/batch/api/version)), refer to the blog post.

The above statment does not mean that batching doesnt work. It just means that the old batching endpoint which worled for every API no longer works now you need to send batching requests to each api

- [www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3](http://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3)
- [www.googleapis.com/batch/calendar/v3](http://www.googleapis.com/batch/calendar/v3)

you used to be able to send all batching requests no matter what api you were working with to

- [www.googleapis.com/batch](http://www.googleapis.com/batch)

That no longer works.

Comment: Batching already not supported, so I think I cant do what I need.

Comment: Why isnt batching supported? They only changed the endpoint it still works last i tried.

Comment: Oh, okay, Ill try and let you, guys, know about results